# Excel arredondando valor 7,256E+18

Tags: php, laravel, microsoft-excel

Aquela velha dúvida com formatação de células do Excel está me causando problemas agora.
Utilizo framework laravel e para exportar os dados utilizo o [Laravel Excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs.).

Estou formatando a célula para tipo texto e mesmo assim o Excel continua arredondando os valores e alterando o final para 0000.
Segue meu exemplo.

Passando a célula pra tipo texto.

```
$sheet->setColumnFormat(array(
'B' => '@'));
```

Resultado na planilha.

```
7,256E+18 => 7256001273850860000 // valor que sai na célula no excel
             7256001273850860168 // valor que era para ser gerado
```

Se alguém puder ajudar, fico muito agradecido. Valeu..

Answer (score 2):

Isto ocorre porque o Excel faz o arredondamento após 15 dígitos, pois utiliza o [Floating-point arithmetic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel). Então os dados devem ser mostrados como Texto (String)

## Opção 1

Formate as Células para Texto Manualmente selecionando as células, depois insira o número com a célula já formatada, como na imagem:

[image: Formato Texto]

## Opção 2

Código de Excel VBA para transformar a formatação da planilha inteira em texto

```
With Sheets(1).Cells 'Para primeira planilha
.NumberFormat = "@"
End With
```

Ou com o nome da planilha

```
With Sheets("Planilha1").Cells
.NumberFormat = "@"
End With
```

## Opção 3

Lendo sobre o Lavaravel, o mesmo pode exportar para arquivos em CSV.

Então você pode exportar os arquivos para CSV e utilizar um código em Excel-VBA para importá-los como String para a planilha.

Sugiro entrar em contato com a Laravel e pedir alguma alteração no código que cria as planilhas Excel, para tornar a formatação das células em Texto. Ou abra uma [issue no Github](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues)

Sugiro ler esta Issue do Github da Laravel: [Laravel 4.2/Laravel-Excel 1.3: Numbers formatted as text still appearing as number #613](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/613)

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o valor com desta forma ="7256001273850860168", como se fosse uma função, ai sim ele vai identificar como uma string.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou formate primeiro o campo como texto para depois inserir o valor, porque assim que você insere o valor no excel ele coloca o zero no final, mas se você formatar como texto e depois atribui o valor funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom dia cara, acho que você não entendeu minha dúvida. Meu problema está quando vou exportar dos dados do sistema. Utilizo o framework Laravel e para a exportação de dados o Laravel Excel. Porém quando vou exportar os dados ocorre esse problema.

Comment: Mas o seu código não esta errado, o problema é no excel, então você tem que formatar o campo antes de enviar o valor, ou passar o valor como se fosse uma operação com string. @LuizGustavoCostaCeolin

Answer (score 0):

Bom, para "resolver" o problema, quando eu vou jogar o valor na planilha, eu concateno um espaço em branco, assim o excel não quebra o formato.

```
$sheet->row($cont, array($val.' '));
```